# reusing an asp.net custom server control in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, controls, httpcontext

I have an asp.net custom server control. Is there anyway I can reuse it in MVC3? My existing asp.net control relies quite a bit on storing the information in HttpContext. If I can somehow make the control go through the asp.net page lifecycle in MVC3, then maybe I can work with some of this information with minimal rewrite in MVC3.

Is there a way I can make the asp.net Httpcontext coexist with the MVC3 HttpContext?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net MVC uses the same `HttpContext` class, through the thin `HttpContextWrapper` class.

However, most ASP.Net server controls will not work in MVC.

Comment: That's not true, they will work if they don't rely explicitly on the view state (which won't work in MVC). In particular I used the reporting control in MVC without any issues.

Comment: Postback is iffy since it relies on view state... Really depends on the control here.

Comment: my custom control doesnt have viewstate or postback. It's pretty lean. It's just within the realms of asp.net pagelifecycle. @Blindy how did you invoke your server control in MVC3?

Comment: @user: Try it and see what happens.  It should also be fairly easy to convert it to a child action and a partial view.

Comment: @user742276, go ahead and just add it then. Make sure your view is .aspx though, it won't work with the Razor syntax (that I could figure out).

Comment: so I added it. The page lifecycle in the server control never got invoked. The good thing is I was still able to call the code in the server control, by invoking specifically in MVC3. The HttpContext class in the server still works in MVC3. @Blindy Can you have both cshtml and aspx in the same project?